# AC Motor Control circuit not working in Proteus

Tags: pwm, 555, triac, proteus, dimmer

I am new to 555 Timers, Triacs and Proteus and I need help to fix a circuit I have built. The intended function of the circuit is as follows.

- Two 555 Timers are used to produce variable duty cycle 0-100%. U4 is triggered by the zero crossing detector and it is used to produce a triggering signal for U1.
- U1 produces the duty cycle output according to the INPUT voltage at its pin 5. The INPUT voltage ranges between 0-5V DC. U1 produces the signal that will control the MOC3021 which will drive the Triac. The Triac then drives the AC induction motor (depicted as a lamp) at a voltage respective to the duty cycle.

[image]

The circuit seems to be functioning close to the intended function as a change in the INPUT voltage varies the voltage across the motor somewhat proportionally. However, the voltage across the lamp is being capped at around 160V when INPUT is 5V. This is resulting in the lower duty cycles to also produce lower results than expected.

I have not been able to identify the fault so any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To use Control Voltage in PWM, datasheet recomends timing R x C to be 1/4 of clock input period; in a 50 Hz, clock period is 10 ms, so you should reduce C3 to 2.2 uF.

For dimmer application, you need an ajustable delay time (0 to 10 ms) from zero crossing voltage. U1 output will be high when capacitor is charging (timing step), so in your circuit, optocoupler will be activate just after zero crossing. I think this not OK, you should connect optocoupler U3 anode to Vcc, that way the triac will be switched on when the timer has stopped.

I am not sure how Clock signal is generated in your schematics. Trigger input to U1 should be a negative edge. I have simulated directly with zero crossing signal V2 (high when grid voltage is present, low when zero crossing), without U4. Control voltage V3 rises from 0 to 5 V.
Notice that CV=0 will correspond with a short time, triac will be switched just after zero crossing, so you will get a near full wave output. CV=5 V will be opposite, long time, triac will not active in half wave, no output.

I hope this can help you.
[image]